# Win XP msvcrt crashes

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-xp, visual-c++-6, msvcrt

Do any one know why an application that always ran on Windows XP now suddenly crashes the msvcrt.dll?

There were only minor changes made to the threading classes, which was done under Vista in VC++ 6.

For all our libraries to work we are Dynamically linking to the MFC dlls.

A newer version of msvcrt does not solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to provide more information if anyone here is to do anything more than psychic debugging for you.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't very helpful, but by far the most likely reason is that you have a bug in your application that, for whatever reason, didn't show up previously. Something has changed somewhere, and now the bug shows up. You're just going to have to debug it.

As a general rule, just because something seems to work doesn't mean it's correct, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem that you are unintentionally upgrading your runtime (which is the problem I have) 
[side by side, automatically upgradeing version of runtime due to policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397196/why-does-windows-side-by-side-winsxs-install-policy-for-auto-upgrade-when-there)

You should check you are using the libraries you think you are.  Process Explorer (downloadable from sysinternals) should be ablee to help you with this.